# How do I impersonate a server with Fiddler core?

Tags: c#, fiddler, fiddlercore

I'm trying to debug an app without setting fiddler as its proxy.

To do this, I've setup fiddler.core based app that resides on an other computer in the network and added an entry to hosts file.

Here's the app's code:

```
    private static Proxy googleEndpoint;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Fiddler.Session> oAllSessions =new List<Session>();

        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += (i) => Console.WriteLine("Before request: "+i.fullUrl);
        FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += (i) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("After request: "+i.fullUrl);
            lock (oAllSessions)
            {
                oAllSessions.Add(i);
            }
        };

        //https://www.google.com.ua/

        googleEndpoint = FiddlerApplication.CreateProxyEndpoint(443, true, "www.google.com.ua");
        if (null != googleEndpoint)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("google.com.ua endpoint mounted");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("failed to mount google.com.ua endpoint");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
        SaveSessionsToDesktop(oAllSessions);
    }

    private static void SaveSessionsToDesktop(List<Fiddler.Session> oAllSessions)
    {
        bool bSuccess = false;
        string sFilename = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss") + ".saz";
        try
        {
            try
            {
                Monitor.Enter(oAllSessions);
                TranscoderTuple oExporter = FiddlerApplication.oTranscoders.GetExporter("SAZ");

                if (null != oExporter)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> dictOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    dictOptions.Add("Filename", sFilename);
                    // dictOptions.Add("Password", "pencil");

                    bSuccess = FiddlerApplication.DoExport("SAZ", oAllSessions.ToArray(), dictOptions, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Save failed because the SAZ Format Exporter was not available.");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(oAllSessions);
            }

            WriteCommandResponse(bSuccess ? ("Wrote: " + sFilename) : ("Failed to save: " + sFilename));
        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Save failed: " + eX.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void WriteCommandResponse(string s)
    {
        ConsoleColor oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;
    }
```

but when I'm trying to access `https://www.google.com.ua` from the target machine, the requests now time out.

Fiddler app shows that it has recieved the request in the `BeforeRequest` event, but it never sends a reply (`AfterSessionComplete` never gets called).

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

How do I do the same for port 80?

Answer (score 1):

I trust you're keeping in mind the fact that, unless you reconfigure the client to trust the FiddlerServer's root certificate, it will not issue a HTTPS request to FiddlerCore. It will instead immediately close the connection upon getting the interception certificate.

What do you see if you attach a BeforeResponse event handler? Does it fire?

Comment: I did reconfigure the client. The problem I have is that the requests time out.